# why is the else statement always run

Tags: python, scope

I'm trying to make a fahrenheit to celsius converter and vice versa but I always end up with the else statement after running. its also in swedish so sorry.

I don't know why it always runs the else statement.

code:

```
def meny():
    print ("""            Programs menu:
           1. Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius
           2. Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit
           3. Exit the program
         """)
def val():

    val = int(input("Enter your choice (1, 2 or 3):") )

    return val

meny()
val()

if  val == 1:

    # Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius

elif val == 2:

    # Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit

elif val == 3:

    # Exit the program

else:

    print("Invalid choice. Try again")
```

Comment: Because you forgot to call the function, e.g, `val() == 2`.

Comment: `x = val()` ... `if x == 1`...

Comment: It's always not a good idea to name a variable with same name as the function. At some point, you might get errors like *"`'int'` object is not callable"* (for eg).

Comment: can anyone debug?

Comment: You are calling `val()` but not consuming the value returned by the function. So technically your outside variable `val` does not contains the value entered by the user in the function `val()`. Also, please change the names of function and variable

Comment: This is an issue of scope.

Answer (score 1):

The root issue here is that the name `val` is being used for different things.

First you have a *function* with the name `val`:

```
def val():
```

Outside of the function, the name `val` always refers to *this function object*. The function object is not equal to any integer, so any comparison with any integer will always return `False`.

Inside the function, you create a new *local* name `val`:

```
val = int(input("Ange ditt val (1, 2 eller 3): ") )
```

This name is *local* to the function and will disappear once the function ends. We say that it has local *scope*. In fact, every assignment statement (every statement using the `=` assignment operator) will always assign to a name in the *current* scope, never an outer scope, unless the `nonlocal` or `global` keywords are used.

You *could* re-assign the global name `val` from within the function `val` by using a `global val` declaration -- but if you did that, then you couldn't use the name `val` to refer to the function anymore. Similarly, you could re-assign the global name `val` from outside the function:

```
val = val()
```

But again, this could only be done *once*, since afterward `val` would no longer refer to the function object. (Also, this would make the program confusing to read and understand.)

Probably the best thing to do would be to use two different names for these two different things.

It's generally best practice to name a function with a verb or verb phrase, for example:

```
def get_value():
```

And then you can use a noun or noun phrase for the returned value:

```
value = get_value()
if value == 1:
    ...
```

Comment: For me the scope is the most important part of understanding this question

Answer (score 0):

You use the same identifier for different things. While this can sometimes be done, it can be very confusing.

Besides, a function name should describe what the function does. For example, instead of

```
def val():
    val = int(input("Ange ditt val (1, 2 eller 3): ") )
    return val
```

you should do

```
def get_value():
    val = int(input("Ange ditt val (1, 2 eller 3): ") )
    return val
```

(or maybe rather `get_choice()` or `get_val()`).

And, when you call the function, you should get its return value into some variable. In your case, that should be

```
val = get_choice() # or how you named the function
```

This way, the function's name doesn't get overwritten, making the function subsequently uncallable.